Summernote - Range selection cross html tag?
Im creating a new button to add a custom span arround the selection :
let the editor be :
lorem lorem lorem <b> ipsum ipsum ipsum </b> 

let the user select the part :
 lorem <b> ipsum 

i would like that the code apply :
lorem lorem <span> lorem <b> ipsum</b> </span> <b> ipsum ipsum </b>

and trigger a window event with selection =  "lorem <b> ipsum</b>"
i saw there is a splitText() and normalize() function in summernote but for now, i fail to use it :(
any suggestion ? knowing that it's just the behavior of a standard but as "bold" or "italic"
